# Saving a variable during entire Tomcat runtime

Tags: java, tomcat

I am new to Tomcat (& web programming in general) and I'm creating a simple web app that needs to return a certain counter. 
The only problem I have is getting that counter variable to stay alive during entire Tomcat run-time.
Can someone please point me in a good direction (a good link would be very nice :) ) because I'm obviously googling the wrong keywords.

So, the idea is to have a class that holds a counter variable, and each time someone sends a request to a certain URL, the counter gets incremented and sent back as an answer. This counter would have to keep track of all the requests to that URL while Tomcat is alive and creating an mysql table just for this seems like a huge overkill.

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: show some code that you've written so far to try to solve the problem and i'm sure people will help you along.

Comment: I don't have the code that deals with the described problem, because I don't know how to deal with it. I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me, I just asked if there is a way to save a variable during Tomcat run-time in web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a quick and dirty answer as ideally you would be using a framework that allows you to instantiate a class and inject it in whatever controllers you have (I'm assuming you're not using a framework, as you didn't mention anything on your question)

But going to barebones j2ee (gods of good software, please forgive me!)

- On your servlet, you'll have an instance of a `HttpServletRequest` on your `doPost` or `doGet` method.
- Call `HttpServletRequest.getServletContext`, that will return an `ServletContext` instance that you can use as a map to store all sort of things. This instance is shared amongst all the requests that go to your application.
- Call `ServletContext.getAttribute(name)` to get your counter class (I would suggest something like an AtomicLong in case you have lots of visitors :D).

Comment: Thanks!
It seems to be what I need. Unfortunately, I'm not using any framework, but this look very easy anyway.

Comment: Glad to help! Once you get familiar with the Servlet spec, I suggest you to spend some time learning one of the MVC frameworks for Java. The Servlet spec was written long time ago, and is fully backwards compatible... which means that lots of the things in there are not ideal.